# Instruments UIAutomation core js files location

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to write some automated tests for my iOS application. Of course, I decided to use Instruments, but its pseudo-IDE sucks. The biggest problem is lack of code completion feature which, as you probably know, is very helpful. Recently I came up with idea, which might be useful. I want to write all these tests in separate IDE, where I can use all its features (like code completion). We can say that it works with one "but". I still don't have code completion for UIALogger, UIAElement, etc.. So I decided to find in my system js files in which these core UIAutomation objects have been defined. Without any success. Does anyone know where are these files? Are they even available in a pure js version?

Comment: It's called "script agent" that translates all the uiautomation js code. However, I have no idea how to do reverse engineering on it.